# How to chain calls, using response as input for another

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, task-parallel-library

Is it possible to use the response from an `async` call as input to another one, somehow chaining them together.

I'm looking for something like:

```
var model = new MyModel() {

    abc = await _service.getAbc(),
    def = await _service.getDef(abc)
}
```

I'm not sure if this is possible but just asking if async/task can handle this scenario.

Comment: What you want is a "continuation". See [Task.ContinueWith](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd270696(v=vs.110).aspx) And here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/chaining-tasks-by-using-continuation-tasks

Answer (score 6):

Your code almost does that already:

```
var abc = await _service.getAbc();
var def = await _service.getDef(abc);
var model = new MyModel() { abc, def };
```

More generally, any `async` method can "chain" methods like this. You use `await` to wire up continuations.

Answer (score -3):

Try:

```
var result = await _service.getAbc().ContinueWith((aa) =>
            {
                _service.getDef(aa);
            }).Wait();
```

Comment: You are unable to use await with .Wait() since .Wait() would be a blocking call compared to await which is asynchronous

Comment: Welcome to [so]! Why and how does this solve the problem? Those who can answer those questions for themselves don't need someone else's code.